# Generated jQuery code in iframe doesn't work in IE but works in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I have code as below to generate JavaScript code in an iframe, then run it. It works fine in FF and Chrome but failed to run in IE. It says

> The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Any idea?

Here is demo link: http://www.gbtags.com/gb/demoviewer/466/empty/6b5417d7-4388-4e30-8055-0d15b10fa9a8.html.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST iframe</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Just a iframe
  <div id="resulttab">
    <iframe id="resultiframe" frameBorder="1" width="100%" height="120"></iframe>
  </div>
    <SCRIPT>
        var iframe = $('#resultiframe')[0];

        if(iframe.contentDocument) doc = iframe.contentDocument;
        else if(iframe.contentWindow) doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        else doc = iframe.document;

        var js = '$(function(){console.log("hello")})';

        var result = '<html><head></head><body>TEST JqUERY<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script><script type="text/javascript">' + js + '<\/script></body></html>';

        doc.open();
        doc.writeln(result);
        doc.close();
    </SCRIPT
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: The only thing that came to my mind it's tha IE is blocking the `jquery` script try with a local copy

Comment: first off, format your code better next time when posting aquestion .. and secound off meet `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">` .. and proper closing tags `</script>` ..

blinding your self with caps in html tags wont do any good !

Comment: i try to format the code, but doens't work for me.

Comment: @Jorge, how can i make it work in IE?

Comment: @terry download the script, and set the local path in your project

Comment: @terry , the formatting is working for around a million questions .. fix the html issues in the code and post the updated code .. this code you have right now isnt correct at all

Comment: @jorge, but i'm trying to create a online javascript debugger, how can i do this for all user's script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
doc.open();
doc.writeln('<html><head></head><body>TEST JqUERY<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
doc.writeln('<script type="text/javascript">' + js + '<\/script></body></html>');
doc.close();
```

Comment: Dont know.  It seems to be something to do with how IE parses document.write content.  I've tried appending scripts to the head/body of the iframe document and it doesn't work, so I'm at a loss to explain why.